# Ternary operator multiple statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ternary-operator

I want to do multiple things if the condition is true or false. I tried to wrap the statements in a `{ }` but it doesn't work. So my code:

```
theId == this.state.correctId ? 
          console.log("Correct Id!") :
          console.log("TRY AGAIN")
```

I tried:

```
theId == this.state.correctId ? 
          {console.log("Correct Id!"); //semicolon does not make any difference 
          this.setState({counter: this.state.counter+1})
          } :
          console.log("TRY AGAIN")
```

This doesn't work. How do I add multiple statements if the condition is true or false?

Thanks.

Comment: You should really just use a normal `if`/`else` *statement* here.

Comment: The answers here and on the link at the top are very good. If you want a deeper understanding, I suggest you learn about the difference between an *expression* and a *statement* in programming languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditional operator should only be used when you need to come up with an *expression* that is (conditionally) one thing or another, eg

```
const something = cond ? expr1 : expr2;
```

Because that's not the case here (and you want to log or call `setState`), the conditional operator is not appropriate; use `if`/`else` instead:

```
if (theId == this.state.correctId) {
  console.log("Correct Id!")
  this.setState({counter: this.state.counter+1});
} else {
  console.log("TRY AGAIN");
}
```

You could *technically* slightly tweak your original code by using the comma operator to combine expressions:

```
theId == this.state.correctId
? (
  console.log("Correct Id!"),
  this.setState({counter: this.state.counter+1})
)
: console.log("TRY AGAIN");
```

But that's very hard-to-read, and is not what a reader of your code would expect to see from the conditional operator, so should probably be avoided.

Using the conditional operator when the resulting expression is not going to be used should probably be reserved only for code-golfing and minifying, but not in *professional source code*, where readability is extremely important.

Comment: One caveat for temporarily adding `console.log` to one of these expressions for debugging purposes is that you can use `||`: `const something = cond ? console.log('yes') || expr1 : console.log('no') || expr2`.  This only works because `console.log` returns `undefined`, which is false-y.  I would not recommend this for anything but a temporary debugging statement, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), like this:

```js
const ret = true ? 
  (console.log("1"),
   console.log("2"), 
   "3")
 : console.log("nope");
 
console.log(ret);
```